# how to handle skewed data while grouping in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am doing a group by operation in which one reduce task is running very longer. Below is the sample code snippet and the description of the issue,

```
inp =load 'input' using PigStorage('|') AS(f1,f2,f3,f4,f5);

grp_inp = GROUP inp BY (f1,f2) parallel 300;
```

Since there is skew in data i.e. too many values for one key, one reducer is running for 4 hours. Rest all reduce tasks gets completed in 1 min or so.

What can I do to fix this issue, any alternative approaches ? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to check few things :-

1> Filter out records which have both f1 and f2 value as NULL (if any)

2> Try to use hadoop combiner by implementing algebraic interface if possible :-

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-pig/9781449317881/ch10s02.html

3> Using Custom partitioner to use another key for distributing data across reducer.

Here is the sample code I used to partition my skewed data after join (same can be used after group also) :-

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Partitioner;
import org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.impl.io.NullableTuple;
import org.apache.pig.impl.io.PigNullableWritable;

public class KeyPartitioner extends Partitioner<PigNullableWritable, Writable> {

/**
* Here key contains value of current key used for partitioning and Writable
* value conatins all fields from your tuple. I used my 5th field from tuple to do partitioning as I knew it has evenly distributed value.
**/
@Override
public int getPartition(PigNullableWritable key, Writable value, int numPartitions) {
    Tuple valueTuple = (Tuple) ((NullableTuple) value).getValueAsPigType();
    try {
        if (valueTuple.size() > 5) {
            Object hashObj = valueTuple.get(5);
            Integer keyHash = Integer.parseInt(hashObj.toString());
            int partitionNo = Math.abs(keyHash) % numPartitions;
            return partitionNo;
        } else {
            if (valueTuple.size() > 0) {
                return (Math.abs(valueTuple.get(1).hashCode())) % numPartitions;
            }
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException | ExecException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(KeyPartitioner.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return (Math.abs(key.hashCode())) % numPartitions;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sorabh, there are no nulls in data for f1 and f2. I modified the code so that combiner will run but it did not improve the performance. Is there any other solution for it ?

Comment: I am not sure but you can try setting pig.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer to very low value. Pig may ignore this value but its worth trying it. It is better then using parallel as you are controlling each reducr file size.

Comment: Actually you can try one more thing :- using partioner to allow reducer using different key to partition data. PIG query will look like - GROUP inp BY (f1,f2) PARTITION BY com.util.KeyPartitioner
PARALLEL 300;   Check hadoop partioner doc to implement key partitioner.  Idea is to choose different column (or may be combination of column) which you feel can give distributed value of your keys

Comment: Thanks Sorabh, I have never implemented partitioner before and so i Google'd it but couldn't find any helpful resource for pig partitioner. It would be very helpful if you can provide any link or sample code so that i can proceed with this solution.

Comment: @AbhishekMishra I have added sample partitioning code in my answer itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sorabh, i modified it per my input dataset and it worked.